# Move and rename files based on the folder they are in

Tags: bash, ant

I am trying to move some files in ANT but can't figure out how to do it.  I know how to do it in a sequential way but can't figure out the "ant way" to do this.

Move the files from:

```
./<language>/<FileName>.properties
```

to:

```
./<FileName>_<language>.properties
```

So for example I have:

```
./fr/file1.properties
./fr/file2.properties
./fr/file3.properties
./en/file1.properties
./en/file2.properties
./en/file3.properties
./ko/file1.properties
./ko/file2.properties
./ko/file3.properties
```

I need to move these up one dir and rename the files like this:

```
./file1_fr.properties
./file2_fr.properties
./file3_fr.properties
./file1_en.properties
./file2_en.properties
./file3_en.properties
./file1_ko.properties
./file2_ko.properties
./file3_ko.properties
```

Is there an easy way to do this mapping in ant?  I don't know what languages I will support or what the filenames may be.

In bash this would be straightforward.  I would do something like this:

```
find ./* -maxdepth 0 -type d | while read DIR; do 
            # */ Correct syntax highlighting

    find $DIR -maxdepth 0 -type f | while read FILE; do

        # Note: this would produce file1.properties_fr 
        # which isn't exactly right.  Probably need to 
        # use sed to remove and add .properties.  
        mv $DIR/$FILE ./$FILE_$DIR

    done;
done;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression [mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) in a [move](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) task:

```
<target name="rename">
  <move todir=".">
    <fileset dir=".">
      <include name="**/*.properties" />
    </fileset>
    <mapper type="regexp" from="([^/]*)/([^/]*)(\.properties)$" to="\2_\1\3" />
  </move>
</target>
```

Comment: Just beat me!  Just figured it out.  Committed my code and just checked back to see if anyone had answered.